# Androidアプリにffmpegを組み込む時に発生するエラー

Tags: android, ffmpeg

Android アプリに ffmpeg を組み込んで使用したいと考えています。

[このサイトの記事](http://qiita.com/hayabon/items/3a0817b4443bd0e4c5af)を参考に `libvideokit.so` を作成しました。

作成した `libvideokit.so`をアプリに組み込んで使用すると例外が発生します。

以下、例外が発生したときのログです。

```
01-08 12:55:18.980: I/Videokit(5477): Initializing AV codecs
01-08 12:55:18.990: I/Videokit(5477): Splitting the commandline.
01-08 12:55:18.990: I/Videokit(5477): Finished splitting the commandline.
01-08 12:55:18.990: I/Videokit(5477): Parsing a group of options: global .
01-08 12:55:18.990: I/Videokit(5477): Successfully parsed a group of options.
01-08 12:55:18.990: W/Videokit(5477): Use -h to get full help or, even better, run 'man ffmpeg'
01-08 12:55:18.990: E/Videokit(5477): At least one output file must be specified
01-08 12:55:18.990: I/Videokit(5477): Stream mapping:
01-08 12:55:19.000: A/libc(5477): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x0000048c (code=1), thread 5477 (ample.img2video)
```

解決策のアドバイスをよろしくお願い致します。

**追記**

> エラーメッセージに「At least one output file must be specified」と出力されていますので、ffmpeg を実行するコマンド文字列で出力ファイルが指定されていないのだと思われます。 –  heliac2001

ご指摘のとおり出力ファイルを指定して実行してらうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

追加で質問なのですが、コマンドに指定するファイルがなかった場合もアプリが落ちてしまいます。これをアプリが落ちないで、アプリ上で「エラーが発生しました。」と表示す‌​ることは可能でしょうか？

Comment: エラーメッセージに「At least one output file must be specified」と出力されていますので、ffmpeg を実行するコマンド文字列で出力ファイルが指定されていないのだと思われます。

Comment: ご指摘のとおり出力ファイルを指定して実行してらうまくいきました。ありがとうございました。

追加で質問なのですが、コマンドに指定するファイルがなかった場合もアプリが落ちてしまいます。これをアプリが落ちないで、アプリ上で「エラーが発生しました。」と表示することは可能でしょうか？

Comment: これ以上コメント欄でやりとりするのは適切ではないと思われますので、「アプリが落ちないで〜」の部分を質問欄に追記していただけますか？

Comment: コメントの内容を踏まえ、質問を更新しました。

Comment: 「エラーの原因は何か」という問題が解決済みで、新たに回答が付きそうにないことと、新たに投稿しなおされた質問とほぼ内容が同じであることから、こちらは重複として閉じます。